# JSF redirect doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2

I have a problem with redirecting a page in my JSF application. My navigation rule look like this :

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{registerBean.registerUser}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/confirmation.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

In my case the redirect tag doesn't work, the URL remains unchanged, and when I refresh the page the registerUser action is executed again. I just have no idea what I'm doing wrong; I'm not very experienced with JSF. Can anyone please tell why the redirect tag doesn't work? Thanks.
(I'm using JSF 2.0 and NetBeans IDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your page is processing without errors? Check your FacesMessages, see if there are any errors queued - these would prevent navigation to the next page.

Comment: Yes, actually there was some other errors, but it's ok now, I solved the problem. Thank you for your answer.